# assigned categories to a news article are not correctly translated

Tags: typo3, categories, tt-news

Here I have tt_news 3.0.1 and a TYPO3 4.3.1. There are tt_news articles translated. If I look into the database (`tt_news_cat_mm`) than in the default language there are the categories 1,2,6,8 assigned. If I look on the translated article it only has the category 1 assigned.

In my opinion the translated article should have the same categories as the one in the default language. If I look into the backend I can only change the categories in the default language. There is no option available in the translated article.

Is that an error for the old tt_news extension?

**Update:**

It seems that the categories are only taken for the first translation. If you change the categories later they don't get updated in the translated version. Very annoying ...